# Cannot install Intel NIC in Debian squeeze

Tags: linux, debian, networking

I've upgraded an old machine to a brand new i3 (Asus H97-PRO motherboard, cpu and ram only) and Debian accepted it quite well, except for the network card. I'm having some trouble trying to install the onboard Intel network card under Debian Squeeze.

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-5-amd64 (Debian 2.6.32-48squeeze6) (jmm@debian.org) (gcc version 4.3.5 (Debian 4.3.5-4) ) #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:34:35 UTC 2014
```

*I have two NICs at the moment, but this is the one that is not working...*

```
lspci -v
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15a1
         Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 85c4
         Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 3
         Memory at f7d00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
         Memory at f7d3c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
         I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
         Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
         Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
         Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
```

---

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

# The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback   
# The primary network interface  
allow-hotplug eth0  
#NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

---

```
ifconfig -a

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 00:08:54:52:5e:0c
          inet end.: 192.168.1.151  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: fe80::208:54ff:fe52:5e0c/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCASTRUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          RX packets:9618 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1738 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:827511 (808.1 KiB)  TX bytes:283769 (277.1 KiB)
          IRQ:19 Endereço de E/S:0x8000

lo        Link encap:Loopback Local
          inet end.: 127.0.0.1  Masc:255.0.0.0
          endereço inet6: ::1/128 Escopo:Máquina
          UP LOOPBACKRUNNING  MTU:16436  Métrica:1
          RX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:108 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:9172 (8.9 KiB)  TX bytes:9172 (8.9 KiB)

pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW 1e:39:9b:b8:ef:4e
          BROADCASTMULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisões:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I also found out that this NIC is known as "Intel® I218V" which, after getting the driver from Intel website, I tried to manually install but, I can't even `make install` because I get this error:

```
Makefile:45: *** Kernel header files not in any of the expected
locations. Makefile:46: *** Install the appropriate kernel development
package, e.g. Makefile:47: *** kernel-devel, for building kernel
modules and try again.  Stop.
```

Comment: have you installed the linux-headers?

Comment: @user1008764 You were absolutely right. Thank you very much for your help, that did solve the problem. I did install linux-headers now, and after that, I could `make install` the driver. After that, added the module, rebooted and I had my NIC up. Once again, thank you.

Comment: For anyone who reads this in the future.  Find and install the Package Similar to [Linux Kernel Headers - 2.6.32-5](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the  `linux-headers` package for the kernel you are using. This contains the kernel headers and are required for compiling modules.
If you want to do this manually, a primitive but effective way of doing so is to run

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-header
```

and install the version corresponding to your kernel. You can run

```
uname -a
```

to see the kernel version you are using. A more automated way is to use module-assistant. The command

```
m-a prepare
```

will attempt to install the kernel header package for the kernel you are running. Incidentally, module-assistant is a reasonable approach to compiling kernel modules.